# Slide show in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I need to make a slideshow.
This slideshow is working on a raspberrypi 4 and screen of 1920X720 here the link: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/4000384651371.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.73814c4d2lxnUR

The goal of the slideshow is that the customer could put on a USB stick in a specific media in map order. The back end works but when I am displaying it on chromium in kiosk modus mode the images are not displayed full screen.[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNVwk.png)

With kind regard for your help and sorry for my English.

```js
var sliderHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
var sliderWidth =  window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
var mediaList = { normal: [], happy: [] };
var mediaLen;
var normalActive = Boolean;
var localhost = "http://localhost:1880/";
var index = 0;
var interval;
var noMediaFound = false;
var leftToRight = true;
var happyhour = {"happyHour": false};

const slidesWidth = sliderWidth;
const slidesInner = slides.querySelector('.ms-slides__inner');

let delay = parseInt(slides.dataset.delay)
let transition = parseInt(slides.dataset.transition)

if (slides.dataset.delay === null) {
  delay = 2000
}

if (slides.dataset.transition === null) {
  transition = 400
}

slidesInner.style.transition = `${transition}ms`

function startup() {
  happyhourrequest = setInterval(function () {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:1880/Happyhour", false);
    try {
      xhttp.send();
      if (xhttp.status != 200) {
        console.log("error");
      } else {
        let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        happyhour = response;
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        return 0;
      }
    } catch (err) { // instead of onerror
      alert("Request failed");
    }
  }, 10000)
  startInterval();
  MediaListRequest();
  media();
  if (document.readyState === 'ready' || document.readyState === 'complete') {
    if (normalActive) {
      if (mediaList.normal[0].endsWith(".mp4")) {
        let vidcontrol = document.getElementById(mediaList.normal[index]);
        vidcontrol.muted = "muted";
        vidcontrol.play(null);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    } else {
      if (mediaList.happy[0].endsWith(".mp4")) {
        let vidcontrol = document.getElementById(mediaList.happy[index]);
        vidcontrol.muted = "muted";
        vidcontrol.play(null);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
  }

}

function media() {
  if (happyhour) {
    if (mediaList.happy.length > 0) {
      mediaHappy();
    } else if ((mediaList.happy.length === 0) && (mediaList.normal.length > 0)) {
      mediaNormal();
    }
    else {
      standaardImage();
    }
  } else {
    if (mediaList.normal.length > 0) {
      mediaNormal();
    } else {
      standaardImage();
    }
  }
}

function standaardImage() {
  let idlist = [0];
  idlist[0] = "standaard";
  noMediaFound = true;
  clearInterval(interval);
  addImg('/home/pi/Documents/SlideShow/Media/standaard/standaard.jpg', 0, idlist);
}

function clearMediaAndAddNew() { //deze functie verwijderd wisselt de media van normal naar happy en andersom
  console.log("clear");
  if (normalActive) {
    clearMediaLen = mediaList.normal.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < clearMediaLen; i++) {
      let clearobj = document.getElementById(mediaList.normal[i]);
      clearobj.remove();
    }
    if (mediaList.happy.length > 0) {
      mediaHappy();
    } else {
      standaardImage();
    }
  }
  else {
      clearMediaLen = mediaList.happy.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < clearMediaLen; i++) {
        let clearobj = document.getElementById(mediaList.happy[i]);
        clearobj.remove();
      }
      if (mediaList.normal.length > 0) {
        mediaNormal();
      } else {
        standaardImage();
      }
    }
  }

  function mediaHappy() {
    normalActive = false;
    mediaLen = mediaList.happy.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < mediaLen; i++) {
      if (mediaList.happy[i].endsWith(".mp4")) {
        let path = localhost + 'h' + mediaList.happy[i];
        addVid(path, i, mediaList.happy);
      }
      if (mediaList.happy[i].endsWith(".jpg")) {
        let path = localhost + 'h' + mediaList.happy[i];
        addImg(path, i, mediaList.happy);
      }
    }

  }

  function mediaNormal() {
    normalActive = true;
    mediaLen = mediaList.normal.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < mediaLen; i++) {
      if (mediaList.normal[i].endsWith(".mp4")) {
        let path = localhost + mediaList.normal[i];
        addVid(path, i, mediaList.normal);
      }
      if (mediaList.normal[i].endsWith(".jpg")) {
        let path = localhost + mediaList.normal[i];
        addImg(path, i, mediaList.normal);
      }
    }

  }

  function addImg(path, i, idList) { //deze functie dient voor het toevoegen van images
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = path;
    img.id = idList[i];
    img.width = sliderWidth;
    img.height = sliderHeight;
    document.getElementById("slider").appendChild(img);
  }

  function addVid(path, i, idList) { //deze functie dient voor het toevoegen van video
    var vid = document.createElement("video");
    vid.src = path;
    vid.id = idList[i];
    vid.width = sliderWidth;
    vid.height = sliderHeight;
    vid.onended = function () { nextSlide(); prevSlide(); startInterval(); }; // als de video geeindigd is ga naar volgende slide
    document.getElementById("slider").appendChild(vid);
  }



  function MediaListRequest() {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // let media= {settings: {happyHourStart: {hour: 0, minute : 0}, happyHourEnd: {hour: 0, minute : 0}}, normal: [], happy: []};
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:1880/mediaList", false);
    try {
      xhttp.send();
      if (xhttp.status != 200) {
        console.log("error");
      } else {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        let media = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(media);
        settings = media.settings;
        mediaList.normal = media.normal;
        mediaList.happy = media.happy;
        console.log(settings);
        console.log(mediaList);
        return 0;
      }
    } catch (err) { // instead of onerror
      alert("Request failed");
    }
  }


  //controls
  function startInterval() {
    if (!isNaN(delay) && delay > 0) {
      interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (normalActive) {
          if (mediaList.normal[index].endsWith(".jpg")) {// index een foto is moet deze gewoon op de tijd gaan
            nextSlide();
            prevSlide();
          }
        }
        else {
          if (mediaList.happy[index].endsWith(".jpg")) {// index een foto is moet deze gewoon op de tijd gaan
            nextSlide();
            prevSlide();
          }
        }
      }, delay)
      
    }
  }

  function nextSlide() {
    if (leftToRight) {
      index += 1
      if (index === mediaLen) {
        leftToRight = false;
        prevSlide();
      }
      showSlide()
    }
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    if (leftToRight === false) {
      index -= 1
      if (index < 0) {
        index = 0;
        leftToRight = true;
        nextSlide();
      }
      showSlide()
    }
  }

  function showSlide() {
    // CSS - transform : translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    console.log(index)
    console.log("happyhour node" + happyhour);
    console.log("normal active"+normalActive);
    if((happyhour.happyHour&&normalActive)||(!happyhour.happyHour&&!normalActive)){
      clearMediaAndAddNew();
      index= 0;
    }

    if (normalActive) {
      if (mediaList.normal[index].endsWith(".mp4")) {
        let vidcontrol = document.getElementById(mediaList.normal[index]);
        vidcontrol.muted = "muted";
        vidcontrol.play(null);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (mediaList.happy[index].endsWith(".mp4")) {
        let vidcontrol = document.getElementById(mediaList.happy[index]);
        vidcontrol.muted = "muted";
        vidcontrol.play(null);
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }


    slidesInner.style.transform = `translate3d(${index * -slidesWidth}px, 0, 0)`
    //console.log(index * -slidesWidth)
  }
```

```css
.ms-slides__inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: 1000ms;
}

.ms-slides {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 720px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">
    <style>
        /* CSS Styles */

        body {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            width: 1920px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        /* Developer Styles */
        #slides {
            width: 1920px;
            height: 720px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .small-slides {
            width: 300px;
            height: 169px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .card-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .card-row > div {
            margin: 1em;
            flex: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="startup()">
<div id = "slides" class = "ms-slides"  data-delay="3000" data-transition="1000">
<div id="slider" class = "ms-slides__inner"> 
</div>
</div>



<script src="slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using the Fullscreen API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Comment: i have rewritten my question to be more clear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292462/fullscreen-slideshow-resolution